# Cookie Initially Set with Secure Attribute loses Secure Attribute

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have non-session authentication cookies that have an expiration of 2 weeks. They are initially set with the Secure attribute. At some point these cookies are losing the Secure attribute.

Could the browser be doing this? When the cookie is first set, Secure is set and SameSite = "None". When the Secure attribute is lost, SameSite is then set to "Lax". So far, I've only noticed this happening at least two days after creating the cookie. I have noticed this in Firefox and Chrome.

I need to start setting SameSite = "Lax", so I'm going to start testing this.

More info:

1. MVC 3 Web App using FormsAuthentication
2. Login is the only way to get an auth cookie
3. I create a FormsAuthenticationTicket, encrypt the ticket, then use the encrypted ticket when calling

```
new HttpCookie("myAuthCookieName", encryptedFormsAuthenticationTicket);
```

4. Web.config is set to require Secure Cookies:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

Comment: I let 3 authenticated sessions on 3 different environments sit for 8 days. 2 of the environments that were secure with no SameSite value are now not secure and SameSite is Lax. The 1 environment that I set SameSite as Lax is still Lax, but the Secure attribute is gone as well.

The created date for the cookies is today though, so it seems like I have some re-authentication code I didn't know about.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/weird-timeouts-with-custom-aspnet-formsauthentication